# Xamarin Form Create Table Problem in SqLite based complex class

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I develop cross platform mobile app on Xamarin Forms.
I try to create tables in sqlite. My class name is 'News' and News class containts 'Country' class.

Create table code and class is like below.

```cs
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class News
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public CountryBase Country { get; set; }
    }
```

and code is something like

```cs
var db = new SQLiteConnection (dbPath);
db.CreateTable<News> ();
```

This isn't working. When i remove the country class it works.
I try to create country table separately but still i couldn't create News table. How can i fix the problem?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SQLite` doesn't allow relationships, and `public CountryBase Country { get; set; }` is interpreted as one.

So you need:

either to serialize your Country as a string before inserting, and you will have this:

```
[DataMember]
public string SerializedCountry { get; set; }

[Ignore]
public CountryBase Country { get; set; }
```

And you need to handle serialization with Json.net manually of the Country.

Or create another Country table, and specify its id in your entity definition:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class News
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
} 


[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Country
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: sad to hear it is not possible but thanks for the SerializedCountry idea. I will try that.